# Deleting rows at the end of each month run

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I am executing my test_function as below

```
select test_function(t.dt::date)
from generate_series(date '2018-01-01', date '2019-12-01', interval '1 month') as t(dt);
```

Definition of test_function

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function(_snapdt date) 
  RETURNS integer
  AS 
 $BODY$
 declare rows integer;
 BEGIN

 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table;
 create table temp_table AS
 select col1,col2 
from table1
where id=01000 and
snapshot_date=_snapdt
group by col1,col2
distributed randomly;


INSERT INTO standard_table
(   snap_date,
   col1,
  col2
 )
SELECT 
_snapdt as snap_date,
 a.col1,
 a.col2,
 FROM temp_table a;

 GET DIAGNOSTICS rows=ROW_COUNT;
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table;
 return rows;
 END;
 $BODY$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It executes for each month from 2018 to 2019.

I am curious how do we delete records based on a specific condition at the end of each month run.

ex: after completing executing 2018-01-01 it should run below statement

```
 delete from my_table where col4 is NULL;
```

Same ,after completing executing 2018-02-01 it should run below statement

```
  delete from my_table where col4 is NULL;
```

and so on for all the months from 2018 to 2019 (statement is same for all the months)

Comment: I don't understand.  A `select` statement doesn't delete rows.

Comment: Can you share the definition of `test_function`?

Comment: @richyen Updated.

Comment: mm, I think I'm still confused.  Can `test_function` be written with `...return rows; delete from my_table where col4 is NULL; END;...` so that it deletes rows after each time it is called?